# i can't get a friend member function to actually be able to access private members

Tags: c++, class, definition, friend

I was reading about friendship in c++(i thought i actually understood it), but when I go to the source code to try it out within some classes, i just don't manage to get it going. I wish to be able to understand WHY it isn't working.

I've already done some research within this website and some others, and i actually found some code that worked, but i really can't see how the logic  i'm trying to implement is different from the it:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/

```
struct B;

struct A{
    A(int _a): a(_a){}
    friend void B::showA(A&);
    private:
    int a;
};

struct B{
    void showA(A&);
};

void B::showA(A& _param){
    cout << _param.a;
}
```

I expect the function void B::showA(A&) to be able to access the private member "a" of class A, but when i try to compile my code it produces these errors:

friendshipninheritance.cpp(10): error C2027: use of undefined type 'B'

friendshipninheritance.cpp(5): note: see declaration of 'B'

friendshipninheritance.cpp(21): error C2248: 'A::a': cannot access private 
member declared in class 'A'

friendshipninheritance.cpp(12): note: see declaration of 'A::a'

friendshipninheritance.cpp(7): note: see declaration of 'A'

Comment: "error C2027: use of undefined type 'B'" <-- Should be a big hint. You cannot just forward declare `B`. It needs to be defined *before* `A`.

Comment: Consider reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/) instead of trying to pick up C++ by going to random websites, the latter being a very inefficient and ineffective way of learning a language as sophisticated as C++.

Comment: The title of this question is rather misleading.  Your problem is simply that you use something (`B::showA`) before ever declaring _what that thing is_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of a thumb, you should solve compiler errors from top. Usually, one error can spawn more errors, and it's not different in this case.

Your `friend` declaration was ignored, because compiler doesn't yet know what `B` is and whether or not it has any function called `showA`. This lead to all further errors.

You can change the order of declarations to make it work:

```
struct A;

struct B{
    void showA(A&);
};

struct A{
    A(int _a): a(_a){}
    friend void B::showA(A&);
    private:
    int a;
};

void B::showA(A& _param){
    cout << _param.a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just reorder declarations.

```
struct A;

struct B{
    void showA(A&);
};


struct A{
    A(int _a): a(_a){}
    friend void B::showA(A&);
    private:
    int a;
};

void B::showA(A& _param){
    cout << _param.a;
}
```

Structure A must know the name of the member of the structure B. That is, the definition of B must precede the definition of A so that the name `showA` is known.